# C# typed function not propagating type to method call

Tags: c#, class

If I have the class

```cs
public class MyClass
    {
        int MyProp { get; set; }

        public MyClass(int val)
        {
            MyProp = val;
        }

        public bool Equals(MyClass obj)
        {
            return MyProp == obj.MyProp;
        }
    }
```

and the function

```cs
bool MyFunc<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    return obj1.Equals(obj2);
}
```

Why when I call, `MyFunc(new MyClass(1), new MyClass(2))` is `MyClass.Equals(MyClass obj)` not invoked?

I know that I must be missing a crticial piece of the puzzle here, but I am not sure what. The function infers the type by the arguments, so it knows it is dealing with `MyClass` objects...

Comment: my first guess would be that you are missing an `override`. If you wanted to override the [Object.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0) method, then the signature is wrong. the parameter needs to be of type `object` and you would need a cast

Comment: Did you override the `.Equals`?

Comment: Because you're not overriding `Object.Equals`. Consider implementing `IEquatable<MyClass>` (and looking up how to do that properly) and you may then also wish to either constrain `T` to `IEquatable<T>` and/or use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` rather than calling `.Equals()` directly, as this reduces boxing for value types.

Comment: I only want to override the `.Equals(Myclass)` signature, but I can't because there are no suitable overrideable methods. Do I need to override the generic `.Equals` and then do a type check and invoke this one if the input type is `MyClass`?

Comment: There is no `.Equals(MyClass)` signature, so you can't override that. VS has some [helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods) to implement these methods that also serve as a reference on how to do it "properly". For simple types, consider leveraging `record`, because it gives you all of this "for free" (`record MyClass(int MyProp);`).

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of using records. Good idea. Thanks

Comment: "_The function infers the type by the arguments, so it knows it is dealing with MyClass objects..._" But your `T` can be _any_ type, not just MyClass, hence why the code in your MyFunc methods calls `object.Equals` (because any type given for `T` will be an inheritor of `object`, but not _any_ type will be a MyClass). If you want it to call MyClass.Equals, you will need to constrain `T` to MyClass. Then the compiler will know that `T` can only ever be MyClass or types derived from it, and it then can use MyClass.Equals as best match without conflict/contradictions with other non-MyClass types

Comment: ("_any type given for T will be an inheritor of object_": Of course with the exception of `T` being specified as the object type itself. And it should have been better phrased like "_any instance of any type given for T will be an inheritor of object_"... ;-) Sigh, i missed the time window to edit my original comment...)